# If $U_1 + U_2$ is finite dimensional, and $\dim (U_1 + U_2) \leq \dim U_1 + \dim U_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Is that possible to prove or give a counterexample to this: if $U_1$ and $U_2$ are finite dimensional subspaces of $V$ , then $U_1 + U_2$ is finite dimensional, and $\dim (U_1 + U_2) \leq \dim U_1 + \dim U_2$.

Comment: Related: [Grassmann formula for vector space dimensions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265952/grassman-formula-for-vector-space-dimensions), which gives an exact dimension: $\dim(U_1+U_2) = \dim U_1 + \dim U_2 - \dim(U_1 \cap U_2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linear function
$$U_1\times U_2\longrightarrow U_1+U_2$$
$$(u_1,u_2)\longmapsto u_1+u_2$$
is surjective, so
$$\dim (U_1 + U_2)\le\dim(U_1\times U_2) = \dim U_1 + \dim U_2.$$

Answer (score 1):

It is true: let $\{e_1,...,e_n \}$ be a basis of $U_1$ and $\{u_1,...,u_m \}$ a basis of $U_2$. Then, it is immediate to check that $\{ u_1,...,u_m,e_1,...,e_n \}$ is a system of generators for $U_1 + U_2$, which implies both that $U_1+U_2$ is finite dimensional and your inequality of dimensions.

In general, by refining this argument a little bit, you obtain Grassman's formula.